# how to set value to field populated by php in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using PHP to populate some anchor tags with data from the database. but after some time I want to change its value with Javascript. but the Javascript value don't change PHP value. any idea? how to achieve this with Javascript?

I don't want to make changes in the database. only change value of the field.

```js
var distance = 0;

if (distance <= 0) {
  document.getElementById("valueName").innerHTML = 'Changed by Javascript';
}
```

```html
<?php
   $invoice = find_by_id($_GET['job'], 'job_id', 'job_post_payments');
   $address = $invoice['address'];
?>

<p id="valueName"><?php echo $address; ?></p>

// javascript code is below this ^^^
```

Comment: If you changed the value using js and want to update the database as well then you will need to hit the AJAX request to make the changes on the database as well.

Comment: I don't want to make changes in the database. only change value of the field.

Comment: Then why you worry. Just change the value using js. As you don't want to change the value of the PHP variable. Next time you refresh the same page then the old values(fetched from DB) will show.

Comment: @sachinkumar I doesn't change the value for  even one time

Comment: I just tested this on my local host and had no issue changing the value of a php variable using that code.

Comment: Can you please show your full code?

Comment: Please provide the full code.

Comment: That code should work fine

Comment: http://main.xfiddle.com/bf1876ac/works.php -> works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Issue see fiddle -> http://main.xfiddle.com/bf1876ac/works.php

```js
var distance = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  if (distance <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("valueName").innerHTML = 'Changed by Javascript';
  }

  if (distance > 0) {
    document.getElementById("testValue").innerHTML = 'Changed by Javascript';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="valueName">
    <?php echo $address; ?>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="testValue">
    <?php echo $address; ?>
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need understand, php it's [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end) technology, and javascript it's [frontend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end) technology.

if you use javascript, you need wait while browser will render this HTML part. Browser must create a DOM tree. And only then you can manipulate with this DOM tree by javascript.

So this is example:

```js
    var distance = 0;
    
    // wait while browser will create DOM tree
    window.onload = function() {
        if (distance <= 0) {
            document.getElementById("valueName").innerHTML = 'Changed by Javascript';
        }
    }
```

```html
    <p id="valueName">Random Street</p>
```